# How to use Oracle PL/SQL blocks and get result through Python

Tags: python, oracle, plsql, cx-oracle

I am unable to understand how to use oracle PL/SQL blocks and get result in python. I can query basic sql queries through

```
cx_Oracle.connect(user=r'*', password='*', dsn=*)
c.execute(query)
print(c.fetchall())
```

But I have a oracle block involving cursor, loops, declare variables to get growth of tablespaces. When I am directly running that I am getting an exception "Not a query"

I cant find a suitable answer for this.

Comment: When you say *"PL/SQL blocks"* what do you mean? Do you mean stored procedures? Or anonymous executable code? You need to show us what you're trying to do instead of leaving it for us to guess.

Comment: Check out [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Also see the cx_Oracle doc [PL/SQL Execution](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/plsql_execution.html) and [REF CURSOR Bind Variables](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#ref-cursor-bind-variables).